# CSS errors under jquery tabs

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, legend, fieldset

I have this abnormal problem in UI when I use a jquery tab control in my aspx page. In all other pages the legend text is displayed( Fieldset and legend display) but when I use the same legend fieldset code in the jquery tab control then they are not displayed in the same way as they are in other pages.

```
 <div id="tab-1">
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="legendfont">Lender Company Data</legend>
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td class="textfont labelposition" style="width: 12%">
                         Lender Company:
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
           </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple solution, in the css of the corresponding legend class, one needs to give the font size appropriately, in other pages, that can be adjusted but with the jquery rab control, it becomes essential to seperate the css for the diffrent controls so that they don't mess up.
So this was the edit in the common css:
Earlier:

```
.legendfont
{
font-family:Segoe UI Semibold;
}
```

Now:

```
.legendfont
{
font-family:Segoe UI Semibold;
font-size:16px;
}
```